# How does the new binding preprocessing feature work in Knockout 3.0?

Tags: knockout.js

So there is a new [binding pre-processing feature](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) shipped with the latest Knockout. It says that along with `init` and `update` methods a binding can have a `preprocess` method that takes a `value`, `name`, and an `addBinding` callback. It's all nice and neat, but

- how are these `value` and `name` being parsed? are they just split by a comma?
- what syntax is safe for them?
- can I expect an arbitrary JSON literal to be correctly extracted as the value of `value` from the binding string?

EDIT

As we know a binding string can contain more than one binding expression. So how does KO know when one expression ends and another one begins? We could assume the binding expression is expected to be a valid key-value pair separated by comma and having a valid javascript expression on the right side however it's not the case as example #1 from documentation shows. Well if it is something different than that what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You get the **`value` and `name` as strings** which containing exactly the text what you have written in your binding in the view so no parsing is involved.

From the documentation:

> `value`: the syntax associated with the binding value **before Knockout
>   attempts to parse** it (e.g., for **yourBinding: 1 + 1**, the associated
>   value is **"1 + 1" as a string**).
>
> `name`: the name of the binding (e.g., for **yourBinding: 1 + 1**, the name
>   is **"yourBinding" as a string**).

You can easiliy create a simple example with :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myFancyBinding = {
    preprocess: function (value, name, addBindingCallback) {
        console.log(value);
        console.log(name);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And if you use it like this:

```
<div data-bind="myFancyBinding: 1+2+'some crazy expresssion'"></div>
```

The output will be:

```
1+2+'some crazy expresssion'
myFancyBinding
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fn7S8/).

Comment: You understand that a binding string can contain more than one binding expression. So how does KO know when one expression ends and another one begins? We could assume the binding expression is expected to be a valid key-value pair separated by comma and having a valid javascript expression on the right side however it's *not the case* as example #1 from documentation shows. Well if it is something different than that what is it?

Comment: You are always attaching a preprocessor to **one specific biding** so you only get the binding expression which belongs to your bindinghandler see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fn7S8/2/ So you cannot get the whole binding expression only the part which is relevant to your binding handler.

Comment: Thats exactly the question. How do I know what piece of the original binding string belongs to my one specified binding? Or to put it differently what is considered a binding exprsssion? Can you give some stynax definition of a binding expression?

Comment: In general binding expression should by a valid JS object definition. What you can write in an JS object literal: `{ prop1: 1, prop2: 'hello', prop3: { complex: true } }` you can write that in a binding expression there are a few edge cases but this a general rule of thumb. But this nothing has to do how this new preprocess feature works.

Comment: @967 But for a complete list of the supported syntax you can start with the expressionRewriting test: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/spec/expressionRewritingBehaviors.js

Answer (score 1):

When a binding string contains more than one binding, the bindings are separated by a comma. Thus `a, b` is interpreted as two bindings, `a`, and `b`. Within each binding, the name and value are separated by a colon. Thus `a: b` is a single binding with the name `a` and value `b`. If no colon is present, the value of the binding is `undefined`.

The name can be specified as a string, in which case it may contain any character except a quote: `'some crazy binding :-)': true`. Without quotes, it may contain any character except the following `,:/'"()[]{}`.

The value can be any valid JavaScript expression, as long there are no top level commas. It may also be any value as long as quotes and opening parentheses, brackets, and braces are matched and there are no top-level commas. For example, if your binding was `a: happy :-)`, the value provided to `preprocess` would be `happy:-)` (spaces are not considered important around operator characters). If it's not valid JavaScript, though, it must be converted to valid JavaScript by the `preprocess` function.